# Verifying CloudBlob.UploadFromStream compleated with no errors?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to save files users upload to my site into my Azure Blob and I am using the CloudBlob.UploadFromStream method to do so but I want to make sure the file completed saving to the blob with no problems before doing some more work. I am currently just uploading the blob then checking to see if a reference to the new blob exists using `GetBlockBlobReference` inside an if statement. Is there a better way of verifying the upload completed fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's any problem while uploading the blob, `CloudBlob.UploadFromStream` method would throw an error so that would be the first place to check if the upload went fine.

I don't think creating a reference for a blob using `GetBlockBlobReference` would do you any good as it just creates an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`. It doesn't check if the blob exists in the storage or not. If you want to check if the blob exists in the storage, you could either fetch blob attributes using [`CloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.fetchattributes.aspx) method or creating an instance of CloudBlob using [`CloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreferencefromserver.aspx) or [`CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj732165.aspx). All of the three methods above will fetch information about the blob from storage and would throw appropriate errors if something is not right (e.g. Not Found error if the blob does not exist).